# React Application on Heroku

Tags: heroku, create-react-app

Have a working React App that can run locally using the command:
`npm start`
However, after deploying on Heroku, i receive an application error message.
The application URL is:
https://earth-weather.herokuapp.com/

The Application Log is as follows:

```
2021-05-12T08:05:27.430345+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: webpack output is served from 
2021-05-12T08:05:27.430467+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2021-05-12T08:05:27.430577+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: 404s will fallback to /
2021-05-12T08:05:27.430864+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2021-05-12T08:05:27.430866+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-12T08:05:27.554932+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-05-12T08:05:27.631647+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-12T08:05:28.728857+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=earth-weather.herokuapp.com request_id=f067160f-79fc-4336-8488-ded7e7eb5ddb fwd="183.90.36.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-12T08:05:30.511115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=earth-weather.herokuapp.com request_id=059ee61d-fe00-4a69-9966-61506da73911 fwd="183.90.36.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-12T08:05:31.219414+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=earth-weather.herokuapp.com request_id=0f53eee2-39a0-4311-b8a3-62cb9ffcde3c fwd="35.185.241.102" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

The forked (public) repository is on [GitHub](https://github.com/ask4physics/react-weather-app).

Grateful for any assistance that can be rendered. - Benjamin

Comment: You should post related log in your question, not external links.

Comment: "i receive an application error message" — Which says what?

Comment: The error message reads: "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served."

Comment: Try pushing your application to Vercel or Netlify and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your application logs the line `Starting the development server`, indicates that the application is running on `development mode` which shouldn't happen as it is a production environment.

The reason,

According to https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/370

> A Procfile is no longer required to run a Node.js app on Heroku. If no Procfile is present in the root directory of your app during the build process, we will check for a scripts.start entry in your package.json file. If such an entry is present, a default Procfile is generated automatically

```
$ cat Procfile
web: npm start
```

In your repository, since you have not specified a Procfile. Heroku automatically generates a Procfile that runs your app on development.

Currently, your react-app is treated as a regular node.js application as the node.js buildpack is used which is automatically inferred due to the presence of `package.json` in the root.

To fix this, you need to use the create-react-app-buildpack on Heroku.

Refer: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/nhutphuongit/create-react-app-buildpack

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The app which i am trying to deploy uses an API key to pull data from a specific back-end server (https://openweathermap.org/api). As a result, Netlify does not apply (https://answers.netlify.com/t/support-guide-can-i-run-a-web-server-http-listener-and-or-database-at-netlify/3078). Have just tried Vercel too, and got the same result (i.e. unsuccessful).

Comment: Is your API Key stored in a `.env` file ? Is the local production build successful ?

Comment: API Key is stored in ```apiKeys.js``` file. Local production build is successful.

Comment: Can you share your Scripts from `package.json` & the Procfile ?

Comment: The current ```package.json``` file can be found at:
https://github.com/ask4physics/react-weather-app/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Wait a minute, by default if you don't specify a Procfile in a Node.js based app. Heroku creates a Procfile with `web: npm start`. `npm start` runs the react app in `development` mode. This is the issue.

Comment: Yes. Thank you @Jagan Kaartik

Comment: Hey, since the query is resolved. It would be great if you could mark the answer. Thanks!